# Power BI - Using Dax to Filter Based on a Group By

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am new to DAX.

Let's pretend I have a table that looks like this:

```
Table A:

status     delivered    sold
late       10           50
late       20           300
early      5            500
```

Let's pretend I am using this SQL query:

```
with cte_1 as (

select 
status, count(*) as [row_count]
from [table a]
group by [status]
having count(*) > 1

)

select *
from [table a] as p1
inner join [cte_1] as p2
on p1.[status] = p2.[status]
```

What would be the dax equivalent of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query return the Table A rows with the status that occurrs at least twice in the table, adding the count of the number of rows with the same status. In Power BI we can write a calculated table that adds the count of the rows of the same status and then filter out those with a count less than 2

```
Result =
FILTER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        'Table A',
        "row_count",
            CALCULATE(
                COUNTROWS( 'Table A' ),
                ALLEXCEPT( 'Table A', 'Table A'[Status] )
            )
    ),
    [row_count] > 1
)
```